# Get duration (in Hours and minutes) between two Date objects - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, utc

Although, I've seen multiple similar questions here on SO but none of them could help me to figure out what's wrong with my calculation. I know I can use library such as *Moment.JS* to simplify my solution but I want native JavaScript only solution.

I'm trying to calculate duration (in hours and minutes) between two Date objects but I'm getting negative (incorrect) duration.

```js
function padNumber(number, width = 2, padWith = '0') {
    const strNum = number.toString();
    return strNum.length >= width ? strNum : new Array(width - strNum.length + 1).join(padWith) + strNum;
}

// Get UTC date time from PHP date (Y-m-d) and time (H:i:s) strings
function getUTCDateTime(date, time, timezoneOffset = -480) {
    const dateParts = date.split('-').map((el) => Number(el)); // Y-m-d
    const timeParts = time.split(':').map((el) => Number(el)); // H:i:s
    const dateTimeUTC = new Date(Date.UTC(dateParts[0], dateParts[1], dateParts[2], timeParts[0], timeParts[1], timeParts[2]));
    // Set back Singapore specific time (GMT+8:00)
    dateTimeUTC.setUTCHours(dateTimeUTC.getUTCHours() + timezoneOffset / 60);
    return dateTimeUTC;
}

function getDuration(timeStart, timeEnd = new Date()) {
    const msDiff = timeEnd.getTime() - timeStart.getTime();
    const minDiff = msDiff / 60000;
    const hourDiff = Math.floor(msDiff / 3600000);
    return {
        hours: this.padNumber(hourDiff, 2),
        minutes: this.padNumber(Math.floor(minDiff - 60 * hourDiff), 2)
    };
}

// Got from server (in Singapore timezone)
const serverDate = '2018-10-18';
const serverTime = '00:22:51';

// Convert server date and time (timezone specific) strings to Date object
const serverUTC = getUTCDateTime(serverDate, serverTime);

// Get duration between server time and now
const duration = getDuration(serverUTC);

// Expected positive value but getting negative as server time is in past
console.log(duration);
```

I expected positive value in console log but I'm getting negative. Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that months are zero-based in JavaScript (i.e. January is `0`, February is `1`, and so on). Your date construction in `getUTCDateTime()` doesn't take this into account.

This line:

```
const dateTimeUTC = new Date(Date.UTC(dateParts[0], dateParts[1], dateParts[2], timeParts[0], timeParts[1], timeParts[2]));
```

Should be:

```
const dateTimeUTC = new Date(Date.UTC(dateParts[0], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[2], timeParts[0], timeParts[1], timeParts[2]));
```

---

Complete snippet:

```js
function padNumber(number, width = 2, padWith = '0') {
    const strNum = number.toString();
    return strNum.length >= width ? strNum : new Array(width - strNum.length + 1).join(padWith) + strNum;
}

// Get UTC date time from PHP date (Y-m-d) and time (H:i:s) strings
function getUTCDateTime(date, time, timezoneOffset = -480) {
    const dateParts = date.split('-').map((el) => Number(el)); // Y-m-d
    const timeParts = time.split(':').map((el) => Number(el)); // H:i:s
    const dateTimeUTC = new Date(Date.UTC(dateParts[0], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[2], timeParts[0], timeParts[1], timeParts[2]));
    // Set back Singapore specific time (GMT+8:00)
    dateTimeUTC.setUTCHours(dateTimeUTC.getUTCHours() + timezoneOffset / 60);
    return dateTimeUTC;
}

function getDuration(timeStart, timeEnd = new Date()) {
    const msDiff = timeEnd.getTime() - timeStart.getTime();
    const minDiff = msDiff / 60000;
    const hourDiff = Math.floor(msDiff / 3600000);
    return {
        hours: this.padNumber(hourDiff, 2),
        minutes: this.padNumber(Math.floor(minDiff - 60 * hourDiff), 2)
    };
}

// Got from server (in Singapore timezone)
const serverDate = '2018-10-18';
const serverTime = '00:22:51';

// Convert server date and time (timezone specific) strings to Date object
const serverUTC = getUTCDateTime(serverDate, serverTime);

// Get duration between server time and now
const duration = getDuration(serverUTC);

// Expected positive value but getting negative as server time is in past
console.log(duration);
```

Comment: Oh, I was aware about that :), but just forgot to take care of while doing calculation. Thank you for pointing that out.